# Ruby class initialize method with default hash

Tags: ruby

I stumbled across this functionality in Sandi Metz's presentation [here](https://youtu.be/OMPfEXIlTVE?t=1819).

It seems that you can define an class's `initialize` function to accept a hash (without a name), and that has is automatically converted to arguments with the key's as names? Is that true? Where is this defined? Here's an example:

```
class House
  attr_reader :var1
  attr_reader :var2

  def initialize(var1: 'var1value', var2: 'var2value')
    puts var1
    puts var2
  end
end

House.new
```

Running this file will output:

```
var1value
var2value
```

Additionally, it looks like the default hash is merged with values being passed in. For example:

```
class House
  attr_reader :var1
  attr_reader :var2

  def initialize(var1: 'var1value', var2: 'var2value')
    puts var1
    puts var2
  end
end

House.new(var2: 'newvar2value')
```

Running this will output:

```
var1value
newvar2value
```

This seems like really awesome and useful functionality. I never realized this could be done. Is it documented somewhere? Or can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyword arguments were introduced with Ruby 2.0.

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html) gives details, and the [Ruby Rogues podcast](https://devchat.tv/ruby-rogues/099-rr-ruby-2) back then had an interesting discussion about it.

Note that this applies to any method, not only to `initialize`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `House` class, you've set a default parameter to be sent to the class if the user doesn't send their own values. That default parameter is a single argument, a hash, that has key/value pairs. And you saw by sending your own value for a certain key, the value is set to the new value you wanted.

If you have many parameters, its usually more convenient to use a hash as the argument to pass because you don't have to write all of your arguments in a certain order. I.e..

```
def method(name, lname, age, city, state, phone, cell)
end

#vs...

def method({name: "", lname: "", age: "", city: ""}) 
end
```

You don't have to remember the order of how the arguments are passed to the method.

Here is a convenient use of passing a hash argument:

```
class Drink
  attr_accessor :type, :flavor

  def initialize(params = {})
    @type = params.fetch(:type, 'orange')
    @flavor = params.fetch(:flavor, 'sweet')
  end
end

Drink.new()  #=> orange / sweet
Drink.new(:type => 'apple')  #=> apple / sweet
```

You set the default params to their relative instance variables. If arguments aren't passed, you have default params set.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. Using your example, I'm asking how it's possible to say `@type = type` and `@flavor = flavor` rather than using `params.fetch`. Check the accepted answer to see what I mean.

Comment: Oops sorry, I see now what you mean